# Rollback after each unit test

Tags: java, mysql, spring, unit-testing, spring-test

I develop application using Spring, Hibernate and MySQL. I created DAO for one of my tables. Now, I would like to test DAO's methods (save, find etc.). The problem is that these methods affect on database data, so I would like to rollback all changes after particular method execution. I tried do this by setting `defaultRollback=true` in `@TransactionConfiguration` but it doesn't work. Below I paste most important fragments of code. Does anyone know how to force rollback after each method?

My table in MySQL is using InnoDB engine. 
In fact, after test execution console contains this information:
`INFO: Rolled back transaction after test execution for test context ...` but changes in database are commited.

UsersDAOTest

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=true)
@Transactional
public class UsersDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    UsersHibernateDAO usersDAO;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        List<Users> results = usersDAO.findAll();
        Assert.assertEquals(0, results.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        Users user = new Users("mchrobok", "12345678901234567890123456789012");
        usersDAO.saveOrUpdate(user);
        List<Users> results = usersDAO.findAll();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, results.size());     
    }   
}
```

Hibernate (hibernate.cfg.xml)

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>    
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

        <mapping class="pl.fp.microblog.domain.Users"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Spring configuration (applicationContext.xml)

```
<beans>
     <context:component-scan base-package="pl.fp.microblog" />
     <tx:annotation-driven />

     <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"    destroy-method="close">
         <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Microblog"/>
         <beans:property name="username" value="root"/>
         <beans:property name="password" value="root"/>
     </beans:bean>

     <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
     <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
         <beans:property name="configLocation">
             <beans:value>
                 hibernate.cfg.xml
         </beans:value>
         </beans:property>
     </beans:bean>

     <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
         <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
     </beans:bean>

     <beans:bean name="usersDAO" class="pl.fp.microblog.dao.UsersHibernateDAO">
         <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
     </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

**EDIT**

UsersDAO (it's generic, but it doesn't matter)

```
public class GenericHibernateDAO<T> implements GenericDAO<T> {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Class<?> persistClass;

    public GenericHibernateDAO() {
        ParameterizedType type = ((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
        persistClass = ((Class<?>) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.openSession().createCriteria(persistClass);
        return criteria.list();
    }

    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(T entity) {
        sessionFactory.openSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a patently wrong way to go about testing.  you should not be testing changes in your PRODUCTION environment and then rolling them back, instead have DEV, TEST, etc. lower environments.  with database and all other system tiers

Comment: This database is my test environment. But my question was different. If changes are commited after each method it has influence on other methods (as I know order execution is random). It's the reason I want to rollback after each method.

Comment: if it is your test environment, why do you care to roll it back?  if you want to revert to the initial state, wouldn't it be simpler to take a snapshot before running the test and then reapply it once you're done?

Comment: defaultRollback defaults to true anyway

Comment: @foampile I care because order of execution is random. Test1() reads all users and the result should be 0. But if test2() will run before test1() then test1() will fail because all changes are commited.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov Yes, I know but I want be sure that this is not a reason of my problem. But thanks for information.

Comment: are you sure that `UsersHibernateDAO` doesn't do any manual transaction management by mistake(for example with an improperly configured hibernatetemplate)?

Comment: I edited my post. You can see implementation of `findAll()` and `saveOrUpdate()` methods. It's generic class but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are opening a new session in your hibernate code, you should use getCurrentSession() instead.

The problem in your code is that your DAO class tries to manage transactions on its own. In modern Spring applications the transaction management should be performed in the service layer.

So it means that typically your service methods should be annotated with `@Transactional`.